# Vimperator broken on newest Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, vimperator

Vimperator seems to be badly broken on my newest Firefox(Don't know whether it has anything to do with it being Developer Edition). "Follow hint" can't be launched, the UI for any command is a mess, it even hangs FF frequently such that I had to force quit again and again. Quite frustrating. And it seems that Vimperator hasn't been updated for quite a while? Is there a solution/alternative available, or was it just me who messed something up. Thanks!

Comment: For Googlers that land here: please head over to the Vimperator issue tracker if you're having troubles. This is the best place to see the current status or to get help. https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs/issues

Answer (score 3):

OK it seems that while public releases on official addons site don't work, latest alpha builds from https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs/releases/ worked.